# postgraphile - how to enable many to many relation field

Tags: postgresql, graphql, many-to-many, postgraphile

I have `Uploads` table.

`Uploads` has `many-to-many` relation with `Parties` table.

the junction table is `Uploads_Parties`, it contains: `upload_id` & `party_id` as fields.

how can i make postgraphile to consider these relation in the schema generation ?

attempts:

1. many-to-many plugin - https://github.com/graphile-contrib/pg-many-to-many. after adding the plugin no effect was taking place.
2. smart tags plugin - https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-pg-smart-tags-plugin/ - i tried adding foreign key relation between the `Uploads.upload_id -> Uploads_Parties.upload_id`, but then postgraphile throw an error.

**Server init code**

```
const SmartTagsPlugin = makePgSmartTagsFromFilePlugin(
  resolve(__dirname, '../../postgraphile.tags.jsonc'),
);
...
appendPlugins: [
        SmartTagsPlugin,
        PgManyToManyPlugin]
...
```

**tags.jsonc**

```
"config": {
    "class": {
      "upload_service.upload": {
        "tags": {
          "foreignKey": [
            "(id) references upload_service.uploads_parties (upload_id)|@fieldName uploadDataSet"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was the `tags.jsonc`, only pointing the `fk` the other way around:
`uploads.upload_id <- uploads_parties.upload_id`.

```
"config": {
    "class": {
      "upload_service.uploads_parties": {
        "tags": {
          "foreignKey": [
            "(upload_id) references upload_service.uploads (id)|@fieldName fileUpload"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

i also have these plugins:

```
    pgSimplifyInflector,
    postgraphilePluginConnectionFilter,
    pgOrderByRelatedPlugin,
    pgAggregatesPlugin,
```